# auto populate fields from opportunity into Quotes with lightning UI

Tags: lightning

I am creating a Quote from an Opportunity and i would like to have some fields copied over from Opportunity into Quotes.

We used to a URL hacking to get the values populated, but is there a way to do something similar with Lightning UI

Update:
Quotes is not supported in Lightning UI yet. But still would like to know if this can be implemented with other objects.

Comment: can you provide more information like when do you want to create a Quote, is there a lightning component or some button? Do you want to open Quote in edit mode or should it be created in background?

Comment: I basically want some custom lookups to be auto populated from opportunity into Quotes edit page. Its like you when you create a quote from opportunity page then the opportunity field in quotes edit screen is auto populated. Similary i want to have some fields in quote page to auto populate from Opportunity record but can be edited